# Create AWS App Runner service with "generic Dockerfile" runtime

Tags: amazon-web-services

According to the documentation for AWS App Runner, you can deploy a service from source code in GitHub. There is allegedly an option to have a "generic Dockerfile runtime" or a "managed runtime." [The documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apprunner/latest/dg/service-source-code.html) states the following:

> Subtopics of this chapter discuss the various runtimes that App Runner supports—the generic Dockerfile runtime, and the managed runtimes for different programming environments.

[image]

At the moment, there are "managed runtimes" for Node.js and Python, however I do not want to use these. I want to use the "generic Dockerfile" runtime in AWS App Runner.

In the AWS Management Console, you must either select one of the "managed runtimes" or choose the option to use the `apprunner.yaml` file in your source code repository. When I examine the [reference documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apprunner/latest/dg/config-file-ref.html) for the `apprunner.yaml` file, the `runtime` section is mandatory, and the only supported values are `python3` and `nodejs12`.

[image]

**Question**: How do I deploy an AWS App Runner service, using the "generic Dockerfile" runtime instead of one of these "managed runtimes?"

Comment: For the source, I think you would choose "container registry" rather than "source code repository". You would need to handle the build pipeline yourself though.

Comment: @user1751825 That would be the "image-based service." According to the documentation in the OP, I showed where it referenced a "generic Dockerfile runtime" for a "code-based service."

Comment: This could be an error in the documentation. I'm not sure why they would support docker in the code-based service, when it can be done using the image-based service.

Comment: @user1751825 They would support Docker because you can build directly from git source, instead of having to implement a separate build process. Part of the value of the AWS App Runner service is that it has a built-in build service, so you don't have to go learn AWS CodeBuild or GitHub Actions separately.

Comment: Yes, they could potentially provide this service. However they'd need to make assumptions about the content of the Dockerfile. It might require custom authentication for a container registry (Dockerhub for example). The only way it could reliably work, is if the Dockerfile only referenced ECR images. I'm still inclined to the think the inclusion of generic Dockerfile runtime may have been an error.